# Stack Overflow punishment for duplication is too harsh

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, duplicate-answers

I accidentally duplicated an answer because I haven't been using Stack Overflow for long enough to know that I could "link" to that answer of mine. As a result, I got 3 downvotes from some super-user and my reputation decreased from 160 to 49! I can't even comment on an answer now. There isn't anything mentioned anywhere about these kinds of punishments.

EDIT not by OP: convenience link for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499772/how-table-creates-in-myeclipse-derby/3695652#3695652) (SO 10k only)

Comment: There's clearly more going on than what you've described. Downvotes are -2 points each, so 3 of them would be only -6. Also, anybody with at least 100 points can downvote.

Comment: I agree with @Greg Hegwill, your reputation graph still shows a rep of ~140.

Comment: Seriously, in my profile, there is nothing else to see except the downvotes: 1 at the original answer and 3 at the duplicated answer. The reputation graph shows still 160, but numeric overall reputation decreased to 49...I really can't comment on answers. And I can't ask the super-user what's going on

Comment: Did it get flagged as spam? That would cause a -100 penalty.

Comment: It has been flagged as spam, but there's no way to see that but http://stackoverflow.com/reputation , otherwise I couldn't find it was flagged... Graph still shows 150-160... btw I don't thing I deserve this, the answer was relevant, not helpful, but relevant to that topic

Comment: I had -500 points for trying to be proactive and 'help' others with the same issue.    http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88078/what-to-do-about-these-answer-dupes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have been hit by spam flags (as @Jon B) points out, but your reputation graph doesn't show this dip.

What do you get if you look at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation? This should show your current reputation. If it shows 140+ (as indicated by your graph), then flag one of your posts for moderator attention requesting a reputation recalculation.

Comment: I suppose you're right, but I can't see that it was flagged as spam, there is only "deleted by community". there is -100 in reputation listing. 
-- 2010-09-12 rep +2    = 163       
 12  3695652 (-100)
-- 2010-09-13 rep -100  = 63        

** total rep 63 :)

Comment: @lisak That would be a flag deletion, though understandably not very clear that it is so. "deleted by community" is that way as it would otherwise state which user(s) deleted the post, and the "12" vote code (the number in the leftmost column) for that -100 is the [code for spam](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump/2678#2678).

Comment: @lisak: There was no "person" that "punished" you.  Flags are done by the community and 6 different people voted your post as spam/offensive.  The person who left a comment was trying to be *helpful* - if you'd followed his advice, you wouldn't have lost 100 rep points.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [answer being discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499772/how-table-creates-in-myeclipse-derby/3695652#3695652) (10k SO users only). It looks like it was, in fact, deleted about a week ago - flagged as either spam or offensive.

As you say above, Lisak, your answer was not relevant to the question at hand, and frankly wasn't helpful at all. It comes across as ranting. I didn't see it come across on the flags page, and I don't think I would have flagged it myself, but it's better deleted than not.

Comment: It was probably flagged as offensive, not spam.  I don't think it's really offensive but I definitely would have flagged for moderator attention as "not an answer."  And I'm pretty sure that posts don't show up on the flags page if they've already been deleted.

Comment: @Aarobot: Changed to consider the possibility of "offensive". Not sure what you're saying about deleted items not showing up on the flags page - I'm aware they don't.

Comment: I wish there were a sensible way to vote-to-delete answers other than marking as spam or offensive. A given answer may be neither, but still Really Really Shouldn't Exist.

Comment: There is - flag for moderator attention and write "not an answer".  It'll get deleted if it sucks enough.