# Can penalty of -500 Rep points be undone?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

I lost 500 rep points as a result of my [{naive} good intention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88078/what-to-do-about-these-answer-dupes/88147#88147) to share a particular answer with those who favorite a particular answer of a question.

I think that decrement is somewhat extreme and am requesting a reversal of the penalty.

On a related note, should there be a badge for reaching the daily cap for negative rep?

Comment: am happy this was corrected for you.

Comment: @Kirk - Thanks! I also appreciate you bringing to my attention how to do things @stack

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I cleared the spam flags and undid the spam penalties, but left the answers deleted.

Comment: We can actually revert the spam penalties ourselves? That's an interesting and good change.

Comment: @Grace: `mod\clear spam flags`. The rep penalty is automatically removed.

Comment: Aye, I see that now. We didn't have that back in the early Stack Exchange 2.0 days, which led to some... [regretful results](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/805/i-just-got-crushed-by-a-moderator "No, hobodave, you really will never live this one down").